# HAProxy redirect SSL only for specific subsite

Tags: ssl, configuration, https, haproxy

i have a problem with redirect http to https only for one subsite. Here is my config:

```
  acl is_root path -i /subsite/

  redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ req.hdr(X-Forwarded-Proto) -i https } is_root
```

when i delete

```
is_root
```

from redirect scheme all site and subsite are redirect to https. I need that redirect only for my /subsite and subsite of my subsite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect `/subsite*` then change the ACL to match the beginning of the path.

acl is_root path_beg -i /subsite